# Appcompat issue in Eclipse Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat, r.java-file

I just tried to develop an android app from Eclipse but it shows an appcompat error as in figure: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkyXw.png . R file is self generated file but it shows an error. Also, in status bar it says: Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. I believe there is problem elsewhere than in R file. But I couldn't locate exactly. Thank you for your desire to help.

[Snapshot of appcompat issue][1]

Comment: Android Studio is the official IDE for android development.

Comment: Android Studio has more issues. It doesn't even let you open R file. In Android studio, it is very hard too figure out where the problem is.

Comment: which Android Studio version u r using, all developers must migrate Eclipse to Android Studio,  also check this https://dzone.com/articles/why-android-studio-better